# How can I make a procedure with define new variable and can use update for later?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am a college student who just started to learn how to code SQL-server. I am trying to solve the following question, but totally lost and have a no idea if I am on the right track or not

Create a stored procedure titled p_fudgemart_markup_retail_by_department which when given the following parameters: 
•   @department  varchar(20) 
•   @amount money 
The procedure will update the current retail price and add @amount for all products in that @department.

The problem is both @department and @amount is not on the table I supposed to use. the professor asked that I supposed to define those two.

```
alter procedure p_fudgemart_markup_retail_by_department
(
    @department varchar(20),
    @amount money
)
as
begin
    insert into fudgemart_products (product_department, product_retail_price)
    values (@department, @amount)


end
```

This is my try, it works, but nothing is happen when I try to update values with this. such as markup the specific department by 3.00

Thank you

Comment: this is not a update query, then how 'The procedure will update the current retail price' . Please check once more, may be someother query is executing.

Comment: I assume you're looking to update the table like so: `update fudgemart_products set product_retail_price += @amount where product_department = @department` or something like that.

Comment: @ARUNEdathadan Thanks! I